# FPDF ouput() saves file with html extension

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm saving a PDF document with FPDF using the following code...

```
$pdf->Output('doc.pdf','D');
```

...but it saves it as 'doc.pdf.html'

Why is it adding the html extension?

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down.  It only happens in Safari and Chrome.  Firefox works perfectly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem for this in my case, was that I was not terminating the script right after I echo'd out the PDF.  I was using a framework and letting it finish out which was causing the problem.  So just add an "exit" statement and it should fix it.

Comment: Thanks @Chad I had exactly this problem and this solved it

Answer (score 0):

It does not add a '.html' extension:

source code:

```
case 'D':
    //Download file
    if(ob_get_length())
        $this->Error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send PDF file');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
    if(headers_sent())
        $this->Error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send PDF file');
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($this->buffer));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression','0');
    echo $this->buffer;
break;
```

so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I know that the $name it is putting in does in fact end with .pdf and not .html.